# Теряется текст при записи в файл

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность

Вопрос очень абстрактен. Кода, к сожалению, минимум.

Имеется многопоточная запись в файл. 100 потоков созданных через `QThreadPool`, задержка `1ms`. Из переменной берется значение, рандомное и заносится в файл с новой строки.

```
    QFile f("g.txt");
    if (!f.open(QFile::Append)){
        return;
    }
    f.write(response.toLocal8Bit().data());
    f.write("\n");
    f.close();
```

Проблема в том, что через некоторое время запись начинает недописывать значение, т.е. дописывать пару последних символов или вовсе оставлять пустое место после себя.

В консольном дебаге ошибок нет.

Пример записанного файла

```
qqqqq:wwwwww
asdasd:assdaas
asdasdasdadsa:234234234
qe
XXewq:231123
etc:222112

asdasd:asdads
```

В чем проблема может быть?

Comment: В том, что надо было сначала про многопоточность почитать.

Comment: @Qwertiy, все достаточно нормально с ней в программе, запись идет. Значения через отладчик видны, но добавляются через один поток в таких местах.

Comment: Потому что это отладчик.

Comment: У вас один QFile на все потоки, или в каждом потоке свой? Впрочем, и так, и так плохо.

Comment: @VladD, да, один. Он внутри потока создается, ошибок насчет different thread не возникает.

Comment: @MatthewHaig: В документации на [`QFile`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html) нет упоминания о том, что параллельный доступ из различных потоков безопасен. Следовательно (пусть знатоки Qt меня поправят), следует предполагать, что он **не**безопасен. Сообщения об ошибке вы не получите, это ж вам не .NET. В C++ обычным «наказанием» является Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @MatthewHaig: Попробуйте окружить операции доступа к файлу mutex'ом (или какая там синхронизация принята в Qt).

Comment: @VladD, как бы вы решили эту задачку?

Comment: @VladD, Я использую QtConcurrent. Думаете мьютекс поможет?

Comment: @MatthewHaig: Посмотрел, что такое QtConcurrent. По идее, `QMutex`/`QMutexLocker` должны помочь. Однако! Опасайтесь просадки производительности. Измерьте время работы с мьютексами, если будет слишком большое замедление, надо будет решать этот вопрос отдельно.

Comment: @MatthewHaig: Если вы до этого не имели дела с мьютексами: вам нужен обязательно _один_, общий мьютекс на каждый файл.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23636/discussion-between-matthew-haig-and-vladd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд, многопоточная запись в файл посредством лишь простого добавления данных избыточна. Так или иначе потребуется использование мьютекса, либо иной техники, которая только и будет заниматься тем, что переносить данные из нескольких потоков в один единственный, который собствено и будет производить запись. То есть, если вся сила многопоточности только для того, чтобы добавлять данные в файл, то ну её такую многопточность.

Методы класса `QFile` в справке Qt обозначены как `reentrant`, что в общем случае означает возможность их вызова из разных потоков, но при этом синхронизация данных должна осуществляться силой мысли автора кода. Проще говоря, методы не потокобезопасны.

Тем не менее, обозначенную задачу можно решить относительно просто: достаточно выделить код непосредственной записи данных в файл в отдельный слот произвольного класса и вызывать этот слот из потока через очередь.

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(file_writer, "write"
    , Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(QByteArray, data));
```

В этом случае не потребуется использование мьютекса, а запись данных в файл будет производить главный (gui) поток.

Ещё для увеличения скорости можно порекомендовать открывать файл заранее и один раз (в отдельном методе или ещё где-нибудь по желанию и ситуации), а в теле слота, производящего запись, оставить только вызов метода, непосредственно записывающего данные.

З.Ы. Единственной ситуацией, когда многопоточная запись данных в файл может быть оправдана, - это предварительная разметка файла под заранее определённый размер с записью данных, предполагающих конкретную позицию в этом файле каждой из его частей. Что-то похожее осуществляется при скачивании с торрентов.

Comment: Кстати, разумная мысль. Только я бы не уносил тяжёлые файловые операции в UI-поток, т. к. UI будет подвисать.

Comment: Да, если нужна максимальная скорость и не хочется трогать gui, то главный поток можно сменить на отдельный и использовать по тому же принципу (конечно потребуется как в примере у @ixSci переместить объект "работника" из gui). Иначе, если скорость не столь важна, но важно, чтобы gui не "морозился", то очень подойдёт конечный автомат QStateMachine. Код от использования последнего вырастет в размере, но зато можно будет легко подключить всякие плюшки для пользователя на вроде анимации прогресса и т.п. Там, кстати, пусть и псевдо, но всё же параллельность тоже есть.

Comment: @alexis031182, можно маленький пример `QStateMachine` под этот случай?

Comment: @MatthewHaig, к сожалению это трудно осуществить в рамках комментария, а если добавить в качестве отдельного ответа на вопрос, то это окажется не вполне удобоваримо для других читателей, поскольку заранее они могут не прочитать наши комментарии. Мой ответ будет выглядеть как ни к селу, ни к городу. Если у Вас имеется некое конкретное недопонимание по обозначенному направлению, то в рамках нового вопроса соответствующие специалисты не откажут Вам в помощи.

Comment: @alexis031182, думаю незачем плодить вопросы. Хватит и примера к коду от ixSci

Comment: Да, если Вам подходит именно многопоточная запись в файл в отдельном потоке, то решение @ixSci наиболее целесообразно.

Answer (score 1):

Проблему Вам уже объяснили в комментариях - разделяемый ресурс не может быть использован конкурентный на запись и чтение, если доступ к нему не сериализован с помощью синхронизирующего механизма. Я предложу своё решение вышеприведённой проблемы.

В моём решении в файл будет писать только один поток и это будет его единственной обязанностью. Все другие просто будут вызывать соответствующий метод, который является практически неблокирующим, т.е. выполняется довольно быстро.
Для этого нам нужно создать класс, который будет ответственен за запись:

```
class FileWriter: QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    FileWriter()
    {
        bool ok = connect(this, SIGNAL(sigWriteData(QByteArray)), SLOT(_writeData(QByteArray)));
        Q_ASSERT(ok);
    }

    void writeDataAsync(const QByteArray& data)
    {
        //Я не уверен, что здесь нужен мьютекс, но лучше перестраховаться.
        //Можно залезть в кишки и узнать точно, но до точного ответа лучше иметь мьютекс
        m_Mutex.lock();
        emit sigWriteData(data);
        m_Mutex.unlock();
    }
signals:
    void sigWriteData(const QByteArray& data);
private slots:
    void _writeData(data)
    {
        QFile f("g.txt");
        if (!f.open(QFile::Append)){
            return;
        }
        f.write(data);
        f.write("\n");
    }
private:
    QMutex m_Mutex;
};
```

Затем, нам нужно создать экземпляр данного класса и поместить его в собственный поток исполнения:

```
FileWriter writer;
QThread writerThread;
writer.moveToThread(&writerThread);
writerThread.start();
```

Теперь из любого места, где есть доступ к вышеозначенному объекту мы просто вызываем:

```
writer.writeDataAsync("Write me to the file!");
```

Ну и в конце не забываем, что нам надо остановить поток:

```
writerThread.quit();
writerThread.wait();
```

Я не компилировал и не проверял код выше, поэтому возможно его придётся немного доработать, но идея должна быть ясна.